# PHP CURL multiple files upload with same key

Tags: php, curl

I have a rest API that accepts multiple files in the same key (written in some other language [Not in PHP for sure]).

[image: Image from postman]

I consumed the **API via postman** and I can able to see **both files are uploaded properly**.

Generated code from the postman and tried sending multiple files.

```php
// PHP Version 7.3 +
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
  'file'=> new CurlFile('C:/Users/Username/Pictures/Image.png','image/png','Image.png'),
  'file'=> new CurlFile('C:/Users/Username/Pictures/Image2.png','image/png','Image2.png'),
  )
));

echo $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

I am unable to see both files uploaded successfully.

I know PHP won't support duplicate keys in the array. It will be sent as one single key which is `file`.

But I am no control over the rest API. It works well in Postman properly. But, PHP doesn't.

Is there any way to solve the problem?

like below,

```php
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
   'file'=> new CurlFile(['Image.png','Image2.png'],'image/png', ['Image.png','Image2.png'])
);
```

Tried sending with index values, But only works in PHP to PHP communication (Not to other languages)

```php
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
   'file[0]'=> new CurlFile(['Image.png','Image2.png'],'image/png', ['Image.png','Image2.png']),
   'file[1]'=> new CurlFile(['Image.png','Image2.png'],'image/png', ['Image.png','Image2.png'])
);
```

Tried indexed array, didn't work.

```php
[
    new \CurlFile('image_full_path1.png', 'image/png', 'file1.png'),
    new \CurlFile('image_full_path2.png', 'image/png', 'file2.png'),
]
```

Comment: It's not possible to post multiple values with the same key name with PHP and curl, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58127427/892493) has some good suggestions. Try Guzzle.

Answer (score 0):

"Tried sending with index values" acutally you are using a string, not a value of an array.

Try it with a real array:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
    'file' => [
        new CURLFile('Image.png','image/png', 'Image.png'),
        new CURLFile('Image2.png','image/png', 'Image2.png'),
    ]
];
```

The classname is `CURLFile` not `CURLFILE` or `CurlFile`.

The constructor signature doesn't allow arrays in the parameters:

```
public __construct ( string $filename , string|null $mime_type = null , string|null $posted_filename = null )
```

https://www.php.net/curlfile

Your code should give you quite some errors, you should look them up in the logs or enable printing them in the browser (set `display_errors` to `true`)

Comment: Not worked. It gives a warning ```Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\..\filename.php on line 6```

Comment: Tried with ```CURLFile``` class for all scenarios, not a single movement.

Comment: @Kuppusamy Did you get any solution for it? If yes, can you please share. I am also looking for this solution.